# Storing fields from a JSON object in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am calling an external web service (Facebook API) which returns a JSON object (see below) in the code behind of one of my pages. I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to store each of the fields from this JSON object in my code-behind (actually trying to get one field, the amount field). The JSON object is as follows:

```
{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","amount":"5.00","currency":"USD",
 "issued_at":81723498712,"payment_id":71283749753874,"quantity":"5",
 "status":"completed"}
```

I simply want to grab each variable (or the one I need), store it in a variable (string, int, etc.), then use it for whatever I need to in my code-behind. Also, note that I am using ASP.NET 3.5 / C#.

Any advise on this would be helpful.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft's Json.NET library. It's very simple to use. You can install it with NuGet packages in your MSVS or just download from the website http://json.codeplex.com/

Then you should create class like this:

```
class FacebookResponse
{
    public string Algorithm {get;set;}
    public float Amount {get;set;}
    public string Currency {get;set;}
    public DateTime IssuedAt {get;set;}
    public string PaymentId {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
}
```

After that, when you recieved your `JsonString` from API, you can use following method:

```
FacebookResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookResponse>(JsonString);
```

And if you need to serialize that class, using JSON, you can use:

```
var facebookResponseItem = new FacebookResponse();
//some initial code here
var sendFacebookResponseItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(facebookResponseItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, code is below:

```
var result = "Code for Call to Facebook Goes Here - Returns JSON Object";
string json = result.ToString();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
Dictionary<string, string> values = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
string amount = (string)values["amount"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Item{
      public string algorithm {get;set;}
      public float amount {get;set;}
      public string currency {get;set;}
      public Date issued_at {get;set;}
      public string payment_id {get;set;}
      public int quantity {get; set;}
      public string status {get;set;}

    }

   Item item = JSON.Deserialaize(JSON_OBJECT)  // check for specific syntax
   Item[] item = JSON.Deserialize(JSON_OBJECT) // even can get array of json objects
```

You can now use these json object in what ever way you want.